# "And God said......and there was light." What does these equations mean?

Tags: electromagnetism, soft-question, maxwell-equations

Today while I was on the Internet I came across an interesting picture, that caught my eye. It's :

[image]

I don't have to explain why this picture seems interesting to someone who knows the meaning and doesn't. So here's my question:

I'm really curious as to what these equations stand for, I'm not an expert in physics, and since this picture has no name given to the equations I can't really search for this online and learn. So that's why I'm turning to you guys. I would be really glad to know the names of these equations, and maybe also the motivation (reason) of the artist to describe it in such a catchy way/meaning of this.

Comment: These are Maxwell's equations of classical electrodynamics in integral form. They are one way of describing light and other forms of electromagnetic radiation. A more modern version of this physics joke would probably use the Lagrangian of the standard model... but you can see here why that won't make a good t-shirt: http://www.quantumdiaries.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/sm_lagrangian_UCDavis.png

Comment: @CuriousOne YAY! Loads of thanks. Can you add that as an answer so I can accept? Also, Do you know a book or a link which has an easy explanation for these ?

Comment: @CuriousOne what did I just see :O so long :o Is my picture a joke in reality?

Comment: You could start on the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations. There you can see that there are multiple ways of writing these equations, too. The derivation and discussion would take a while, though... it typically fills a pretty good physics textbook.

Comment: @CuriousOne yeah it would... or at least [CERN thinks so](http://design-guidelines.web.cern.ch/sites/design-guidelines.web.cern.ch/files/u6/Equation%20Tshirt.png)

Comment: @Danu: Hah! That's cheating! :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133158/2451

Comment: What god would denote $d\mathbf{S}$ by $\partial \vec{s}$? And the sign in Faraday's law!?

Comment: I would venture to offer the hypothesis that it wasn't god who had this t-shirt printed. It was most likely not even a physicist. I leave it to another person to discuss the non-obvious differences between god and a physicist. :-)

Comment: G-d would have never said Eq.4 because it is wrong!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are Maxwell's equations of classical electrodynamics in integral form. They are one way of describing light and other forms of electromagnetic radiation. A more modern version of this physics joke would probably use the Lagrangian of the standard model... but you can see here why that won't make a good t-shirt: http://www.quantumdiaries.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/sm_lagrangian_UCDavis.png

As for a good textbook... the classic text is something like "the" Jackson "Classical Electrodynamics", but it won't do any good for a beginner. I would probably not even try to learn electrodynamics from a textbook, if you are interested. The better way would be to listen to an actual physics class online. MIT has Lewin's phenomenological class on electricity and magnetism online: https://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/electricity-magnetism/id341599922?mt=10#ls=1&uo=8&at=10lqkA. Something like that is a good preparation for the required theory work to understand Maxwell's equations. You could follow that up with e.g. Yale's class on electrodynamics starting here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NK-BxowMIfg

I've been watching Shankar's course for a couple of minutes now... and I like it quite a bit. He is not only teaching about electricity and magnetism, but he has a lot of important things to say about the structure of physics and good physical thinking in general.

Comment: You should add a derivation of the wave equation! ;)

Comment: @Danu... that's why I made it a comment and not an answer first... I am lazy!